# Run time error: 424 : Object required when I try to reach range and use range data

Tags: vba, range

I am trying to highligh new excel the same way as old excel and data is large .So I saved the data in range and tried to do find, count if functions in range .But it keep showing "object not find error".I really don't get it since I defined the range object well. Here are part of my codes .I tried to debug by "RangSe1(1, 1).Activate" after I defined the RangSe1 object and it give me the 424 error even from here . I am really confused .

```
 Sub Morningsmall()

 Dim strfile As String
 Dim iLastrow, iColor, iFind, iLastrow1, iLastrow2, iLastrow3, iLastrow4,   iRow As Long
 Dim RangSe1, RangSo1, RangSe2, RangSo2, RangS As Range


 Dim wbLastday, wbToday As Workbook
 Dim wsSettle1, wsSettle2, wsSophis1, wsSophis2 As Worksheet

    With Application

        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculate
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
    End With


  'Open yesterday's file
   MsgBox "Open Yesterday's Settlement Report"
   strfile = Application.GetOpenFilename
   If strfile <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open strfile

Set wbLastday = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSettle1 = wbLastday.Sheets("SettlementReport")
Set wsSophis1 = wbLastday.Sheets("Sophis")

iLastrow1 = wsSettle1.Cells(wsSettle1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
iLastrow2 = wsSophis1.Cells(wsSophis1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

RangSe1 = wsSettle1.Range("A1:AQ" & iLastrow1)
RangSo1 = wsSophis1.Range("A1:AJ" & iLastrow2)


RangSe1(1, 1).Activate

...
...
...


For i = 2 To iLastrow3
    iFind = RangSe2(i, 1)
    'a = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rang, iFind)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsSettle1, iFind) > 0 Then

   'range1.Find("test id", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If RangSe1(wsSettle1.Cells.Find(what:=iFind).Row, 6) = RangSe2(i,           6)     Then
       iColor = RangSe1.Find(what:=iFind).Interior.Color
           If iColor <> 16777215 Then
                 wsSettle2.Rows(i).Interior.Color = iColor
           End If
       End If
 End If

...
...
...
```

Comment: You declared `RangSE1` as a `Variant`, and then didn't `Set` it, so it doesn't know you were trying to use it as a `Range`

Answer (score 1):

Your lines saying

```
Dim RangSe1
'...
RangSe1 = wsSettle1.Range("A1:AQ" & iLastrow1)
```

is equivalent to

```
Dim RangSe1 As Variant
'...
RangSe1 = wsSettle1.Range("A1:AQ" & iLastrow1).Value
```

which will create a `Variant` array dimensioned as `1 To iLastrow1, 1 To 43`.  You can't use an `Activate` method on the `(1, 1)`th position of an array, because an array is not an object and therefore does not have methods or properties.

---

You have two major mistakes that are causing your code to not do what you expect:

1) You are not defining your variables correctly because:

```
Dim RangSe1, RangSo1, RangSe2, RangSo2, RangS As Range
```

is equivalent to :

```
Dim RangSe1 As Variant, RangSo1 As Variant, RangSe2 As Variant, RangSo2 As Variant, RangS As Range
```

You should use:

```
Dim RangSe1 As Range, RangSo1 As Range, RangSe2 As Range, RangSo2 As Range, RangS As Range
```

2) You are not using the `Set` keyword when assigning a reference to your `Range` objects so, for instance,

```
RangSe1 = wsSettle1.Range("A1:AQ" & iLastrow1)
```

should be

```
Set RangSe1 = wsSettle1.Range("A1:AQ" & iLastrow1)
```

Comment: Hi It solves my question so well .Thank you ! Although I wonder why I can't define all range objects as range by define together?

Comment: And I have a data set of 150000. In this case my look always get stuck even if I loop by range .Is there anyway that I can fasten the loop process within 5 mins?

Comment: @SusanLiu "I wonder why I can't define all range objects as range by define together?" - You can do `Dim x, y, z As Range` but that is treated by VBA as `Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, z As Range`.  If you don't include an `As type` declaration, VBA assumes the variable is to be declared as a `Variant`.  So if you want multiple variables to all be declared as `Range` objects, you need to declare all of them `As Range`, i.e. `Dim x As Range, y As Range, z As Range`.

Comment: @SusanLiu Re speed - if you were only accessing the values of your range, and not the formatting, I would recommend that you read the data into an array, then perform your processing against the array, and then (when finished) write the array back to the sheet.  But because you are processing colours, you can't do that that way.